# Code highlighter not working in the quill editor

Tags: javascript, quill

I followed the documentation of Quill, but the syntax highlighting is not working. By the way, even the example on the [Quill playground webpage](https://quilljs.com/playground/#quill-playground) is not working, while the example on the [Quill home page](https://quilljs.com/) is working. Here is my code and a link to CodePen.

**HTML**

```
<div id="editor-container"><pre>for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  printf ("Hello");</pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

Here is a CodePen showing the issue:
https://codepen.io/imabot2/pen/mdJwdZy

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the [Syntax Highlighter Module](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/syntax/)

Include [HighLightJs](https://highlightjs.org/download/);

```
<!-- Local file -->
<script href="highlight.js"></script>

<!-- CloudFare CDN -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.18.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

Enable module;

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    modules: {
        syntax: true,                          # <-- Enable module
        toolbar: [
            [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
            ['image', 'code-block']
        ]
    },
    placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
    theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

Updated codePen;
https://codepen.io/0stone0/pen/poJwBzw

Comment: Does not work. Colors are not applied

Comment: What browser are you using @SergeyOrlov? The pen is colorized in recent Chrome...